# Print document with pdfjs in Edge browser

Tags: printing, microsoft-edge, pdf.js

I'm trying to print a pdf document using pdfjs in Edge Browser. The problem is that print does not work, the print dialog does not open or it opens after a long time (>1 min). Than I tested demo on pdfjs website (http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html), when I try to print the document it takes more than 2 minutes to "Preparing document for printing.." and after that all rendered pages in print preview have the bottom half missing..

[image]

Is this a known problem for pdfjs ? Is there any solution/workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

A little css should fix this!

```css
.page {
    position: relative;
    background-clip: content-box;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```